# jquery and spring problems

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm recently trying to learn Spring, and I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'm pretty sure this problem has been addressed before. I've tried lots of posted solutions and nothing seems to work, I'm missing something.

It's a simple JSP with a button to access a simple javascript. Here's the error I get:

> springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springServlet-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 68; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.

I know this error comes from my XML file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.wipro.controller" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/js/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

As you can see, the tag mvc:resources is there, I don't know if it's not well written or I'm missing a property, and I'm running out of sources.

Here's my JSP and my Script, it works on the snipplet but when I run it on tomcat the button doesn't do anything:

```js
function btnFunction(){
 alert("hello!");
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type="text/css">
 div{
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 30%;
 }
</style>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/script.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="display-4">INDEX</h1>
 <div>
  <ul class="list-group">
   <li>
    <a href="listBooks.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">BOOK DETAILS</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="btnFunction()">CLICK</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this is important but I'm not using Maven, just a Dynamic Web Application, I'm also showing the project structure, just in case:

[image: Figure 1]